# Reindex Not Happening Automatically Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, cron, reindex, stock

Every time I update a product stock in magento it updates perfectly in the backend but only when I manually run a reindex via SSH does it update on the front end.

Very annoying when I am sometimes updating stock several times a day with deliveries.

So for example a product has 0 in stock, if i change to qty 5  the back end shows in stock qty 5 but front end still shows out of stock.
After reindex it updates on the front end.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: How do you set the reindex to happen by schedule or on save

Comment: Have you set proper cron jobs?

Answer (score 2):

You can change indexing settings to, update on save,

here is the difference:

Update on Save :The index is set to update whenever a change is saved.

Update on Schedule :The index is set to update on schedule according to a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Cron, and Cron logs.

You can also run

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```

Cron jobs are responsible for reindex

Answer (score 0):

***First Remove old Cron :-***

php bin/magento cron:remove

***After that install New Cron :-***

php bin/magento cron:install